# Hyphenation in X year old person

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

> The thirty-five-year-old patient

Is that correct?

Or one of

> The thirty five-year old patient

> The thirty-five-year old patient

> The thirty-five year-old patient

> The thirty five year old patient

etc.

What's the correct way to hyphenate phrases like this?

Comment: Also, the [Wikipedia article on the hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) has the example 'twenty-eight-year-old woman' (in the section on compound modifiers).

Answer (score 1):

Numbers such as *thirty-five* are hyphenated.

When used attributively or as a noun, *x-year-old* is hyphenated.

Therefore, a *thirty-five-year-old patient* is thus hyphenated, but

> The patient was thirty-five years old.

Comment: The over-prescriptive answer at the duplicate at least added supporting evidence from CMoS. I'll be back.

Comment: The answer by @KarlG is correct. I would add a contrasting example with 'x-year-old' being used as a noun, e.g. "The patient was a thirty-five-year-old.

Comment: Ultimately what is "correct" and what isn't could vary by style guide, where you live, personal choice etc. All I can say is that, as one who has completed a humanities degree at a British university within the last ten years, your choice would be my own personal preference.